# Infinitely many primes that are the sum of a power of 2 and a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Are there infinitely many primes $p$, for which there exist positive integers $m$ and $n$, such that
$2^m+n^2=p$?

Answer (score 2):

**Not an answer, but my link didn't work in a comment :(**

Have you considered the easier question of whether or not there are infinitely many primes of the form $2+n^2$? Note that $$2+1^2=3, 2+3^2=11, 2+9^2=83,2+15^2=227, 21^2+2=443,33^2+2=1091,39^2+2=1523,45^2+2=2027,57^2+2=3251,81^2+2=6563$$ are primes, I can imagine there are infinitely many of those already.

Typically these are open problems. I refer you to [this question and it's answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) for more on that.

Comment: Also, if you fix n=1, then it becomes the Fermat conjecture about primes of the form 2^q+1

Comment: Well, Fermat conjectured that all number of the form 2^(2^t)+1 are primes which was proven wrong but the question if there are infinite primes is still open.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ : You're absolutely right! (how did I miss that - facepalm -) Goes to show how ridiculously easy it is to ponder these type of questions and run into open problems! I guess one could also wonder whether there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p!-1$ (or $p!+1$) is also prime. I bet that's an open problem too.